# Hide Replace divs with replaceWith() issues

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What I am trying to do is replace the entire div with another div, each time leading to a new div with links to replace it. I'm close, but Only the first selection works properly.

Only one div should show at a time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link2").click(function() {
    $(".changesections").replaceWith($("#section2").show());
  });
  $(".link1").click(function() {
    $(".changesections").replaceWith($("#section1").show());
  });
  $(".link3").click(function() {
    $(".changesections").replaceWith($("#section3").show());
  });
  $("#section2").hide();
  $("#section3").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="changesections">
  <span class="link1">Link 1</span>
  <p>
    <span class="link2">Link 2</span>
    <p>
      <span class="link3">Link 3</span>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="changesections">
  <span class="link1">**Link 1</span>
  <p>
    <span class="link2">**Link 2</span>
    <p>
      <span class="link3">**Link 3</span>
</div>

<div id="section3" class="changesections">
  <span class="link1">****Link 1</span>
  <p>
    <span class="link2">****Link 2</span>
    <p>
      <span class="link3">****Link 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: THey have the same classes, but different IDs.

Comment: Oh! oops. I see what you mean, Thanks! That's probably my issue.

Comment: Fixed the multiple similar IDs

Comment: While you don't *have* to close a `<p>` tag it might help if you do, that way it becomes easier to recognise when there are errors in the written HTML, and makes code more readable; especially when auto-indentation is used (such as when you use the 'tidy' feature on the Snippet editor, or format in VS Code or other IDE). "*I am trying to ... replace the entire div with another div*" - why? Why are you not showing/hiding the existing elements instead of removing them from the document?

Comment: please take time and make a working code-snippet, don't link to an outside source, links can get obsolete

Comment: Following from @DavidsaysreinstateMonica , there a few, if any, good reasons to **not** explicitly close the `p` tag

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica - I tried the show/hide mechanism but wasn't able to get it work with what I'm doing. The HTML above is just an example. I only added the P element for aesthetics.

Comment: Rebecca: rather than adding elements for aesthetics, show the HTML you're working with (or at the very least correct, well-formatted HTML that accurately represents the code you're working with). We're happy to help, but if we're distracted from your real problem trying to tidy up the other problems we find it doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica  I must be exhausted. And my eyes have gone sideways. I decided to give the show/hide another go and it worked. I think it wasn't working because of my multiple IDs which I likely had earlier and which you pointed out. Thank you beyond thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your idea is only hide/show, then you can do this (I've improved your code in order to be DRY):

```js
const sections = $('.changesections')

$('#section2, #section3').hide()

function toggleSection(link, div) {
  $(link).on('click', e => {
    console.log(`toggled ${div}`)
    sections.hide()
    $(div).show()
  })
}

for (let i = 1; i <= sections.length; i++)
  toggleSection(`.link${i}`, `#section${i}`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="changesections">
  <span class="link1">Link 1</span>
  <span class="link2">Link 2</span>
  <span class="link3">Link 3</span>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="changesections">
  <span class="link1">**Link 1</span>
  <span class="link2">**Link 2</span>
  <span class="link3">**Link 3</span>
</div>

<div id="section3" class="changesections">
  <span class="link1">****Link 1</span>
  <span class="link2">****Link 2</span>
  <span class="link3">****Link 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully too. The hide/show. I had tried it before and wasn't able to get it to work, but as someone pointed out, I had multiple similar IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a little CSS to help you and as you've named things links, I'd actually use links, which may also give you some minor SEO benefits. Then  I'd literally hide and show instead of changing the DOM

```js
$(".changesections a").on("click", function(e){  
  //Get the arribute not .href as it qualifies the URL
  //Hide others
  $(".changesections").not($(this).attr("href")).hide();
  //Show the one you want.
  $($(this).attr("href")).show();
});
```

```css
.changesections {display:none;}
#section1 {display:block;}
/*Below is just to demonstrate the change*/
#section1 a{color:red;}
#section2 a{color:blue;}
#section3 a{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1" class="changesections">
  <a href="#section1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#section2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#section3">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div id="section2" class="changesections">
  <a href="#section1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#section2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#section3">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div id="section3" class="changesections">
  <a href="#section1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#section2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#section3">Link 3</a>
</div>
```